# Why git status says I have differences whereas git fetch origin shows nothing?

Tags: git

With `git status`, I get this message:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and
have 9 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

With `git fetch -v origin`, I get

```
[up to date]      master     -> origin/master
```

Aren't the two in contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 branches in play here, instead of 2:

- Your `master`
- Your `origin/master`
- The remote's `master`

`git status` is comparing `master` and `origin/master` (both local branches).

`git fetch`, however, is comparing the remote's `master` and your local `origin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` is telling you that origin/master in your repository and master in **the origin repository** are the same. `git status` is telling you that origin/master in your repository and master in **your repository** have diverged. There's no contradiction, since they're talking about different things.

Comment: The wording is confusing with all the "copy of", and potentially wrong. There is no "copy of" `origin/master` (which is a copy in itself, of the remote's branch). Also, there is no `origin/master` in the remote, nor a copy of it.